# How to change external variable's value inside a goroutine closure

Tags: go, concurrency, closures, goroutine

```
func (this *l) PostUpload(ctx *Context) {

    //ctx.Response.Status = 500

    l, err := models.NewL(this.Config)
    go func() {
        err = l.Save(file) 
        if err != nil {
            ctx.Response.Status = 500
            ctx.Response.Body = err
        } else {
            ctx.Response.Status = 204
        }
    }()
}
```

How to change `ctx.Response.Status` value inside the goroutine closure?

Comment: a channel as a param for the anonymous function can fix this, but any other solutions?

Comment: This code is likely not thread safe. Why do you need to start a new goroutine here?

Comment: to handle request in new coroutine, however, you are right, there's no need   to start a new goroutine

Comment: but still, is there a way to change external variable's value inside a closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no guarantee to observe changes made to the value of a variable in another goroutine *without synchronization*. See [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) for details.

So if you want to change `ctx.Response.Status` in another goroutine, for this change to be guaranteed to be visible in the caller goroutine use synchronization.

There are multiple synchronization primitives. You can use channels or the [`sync`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) package.

#### Using channels:

```
ch := make(chan int)

go func() {
    err = l.Save(file) 
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Response.Status = 500
        ctx.Response.Body = err
    } else {
        ctx.Response.Status = 204
    }
    ch <- 0 // Signal that ctx is updated
    // goroutine may do other works (not related to changing ctx)
}()

<- ch // Wait for the goroutine to finish updating ctx
```

#### Using [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup):

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)

go func() {
    err = l.Save(file) 
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Response.Status = 500
        ctx.Response.Body = err
    } else {
        ctx.Response.Status = 204
    }
    wg.Done() // Signal that ctx is updated
    // goroutine may do other works (not related to changing ctx)
}()

wg.Wait() // Wait for the goroutine to finish updating ctx
```

#### Using [`sync.Mutex`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex):

```
m := sync.Mutex{}
m.Lock()

go func() {
    err = l.Save(file) 
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Response.Status = 500
        ctx.Response.Body = err
    } else {
        ctx.Response.Status = 204
    }
    m.Unlock() // Signal that ctx is updated
    // goroutine may do other works (not related to changing ctx)
}()

m.Lock() // Wait for the goroutine to finish updating ctx
```

**Note:**

It is good practice to signal the completion (ctx update in your case) using `defer` so that if the started goroutine would end in some unexpected way (e.g. runtime panic), the caller goroutine would not get blocked forever. Note that however in this case the completion signal will only be sent at the end of the anonymous function (that's when deferred functions are executed).